# Conversion of list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary-comprehension

How shall I convert a string as given below into a dictionary in the given way?

```
sentence = "python is a programming language"
```

Output:

```
{'p' : ['python', 'programming'], 'i' : ['is'], 'a' : ['a'], 'l' : ['language']}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have split the string to convert it into a list, storing that into a new object
then I have created an empty dictionary named 'd'.  Then while using the for loop i was trying to sort it, but wasn't able to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "python is a programming language"
d = {}
for s in sentence.split():
    if s[0] not in d.keys():
        d[s[0]] = [s]
    else:
        d[s[0]].append(s)
```